# GoogleMap Api - initialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

How can I initiliaze the google map without using the body tag(body onload=.....)

I can not use:  `<body onload="initialize()">`

I need to use some Javascript to get the same result..but I don't know how, i tried:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>  
      $(window).load(function() {
         initialize()
      });
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i just got it:

```
window.onload = function() {
        initialize()
    };
```

Can be closed..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can also do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    initialize();
}
```